# How can I unflatten a list of dictionaries in python 2.7 as in the example?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am using python 2.7. I have an input that is a list of dictionaries. In my system a user can add macrocategories. This macrocategories can contain 0 or more categories. And the categories contained by the macrocategories, can contain 0 or more microcategories. Macrocategories, categories and microcategories are unique. The input list of dictionaries is already ordered first by macrocategory, after by category and last by microcategory.

```
    input = [{
      'desc_category': 'category1',
      'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory1',
      'desc_microcategory': 'microcategory1',
      'id_category': '1',
      'id_macrocategory': '1',
      'id_microcategory': '1',
      },
     {
      'desc_category': 'category2',
      'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory1',
      'desc_microcategory': None,
      'id_category': '2',
      'id_macrocategory': '1',
      'id_microcategory': '0',

      },
     {
      'desc_category': 'category5',
      'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory1',
      'desc_microcategory': None,
      'id_category': '5',
      'id_macrocategory': '1',
      'id_microcategory': '0',
      },

     {
      'desc_category': 'category21',
      'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory2',
      'desc_microcategory': None,
      'id_category': '21',
      'id_macrocategory': '2',
      'id_microcategory': '0',
      },
     {
      'desc_category': 'category28',
      'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory2',
      'desc_microcategory': None,
      'id_category': '28',
      'id_macrocategory': '2',
      'id_microcategory': '0',
      },

     {
      'desc_category': 'category31',
      'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory3',
      'desc_microcategory': 'microcategory71',
      'id_category': '31',
      'id_macrocategory': '3',
      'id_microcategory': '71',
     },
     {
      'desc_category': 'category31',
      'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory3',
      'desc_microcategory': 'microcategory72',
      'id_category': '31',
      'id_macrocategory': '3',
      'id_microcategory': '72',
     },
     {
      'desc_category': None,
      'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory4',
      'desc_microcategory': None,
      'id_category': '0',
      'id_macrocategory': '4',
      'id_microcategory': '0',
      }
    ]
```

the output must be:

```
    output = [
        {   'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory1',
            'id_macrocategory': 1,
            'categories': [
                {   'desc_category': 'category1',
                    'id_category': 1,
                    'microcategories': [
                        {   'desc_microcategory': 'microcategory1',
                            'id_microcategory': 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {   'desc_category': 'category2',
                    'id_category': 2,
                    'microcategories': []
                },
        
                {   'desc_category': 'category5',
                    'id_category': 5,
                    'microcategories': []
                }
            ]
        },      
        {   'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory2',
            'id_macrocategory': 2,
            'categories': [
                {   'desc_category': 'category21',
                    'id_category': 21,
                    'microcategories': []
                },
                {   'desc_category': 'category28',
                    'id_category': 28,
                    'microcategories': []
                }
            ]
        },      
        {   'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory3',
            'id_macrocategory': 3,
            'categories': [
                {   'desc_category': 'category31',
                    'id_category': 31,
                    'microcategories': [
                        {   'desc_microcategory': 'microcategory71',
                            'id_microcategory': 71
                        },
                        {   'desc_microcategory': 'microcategory72',
                            'id_microcategory': 72
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },  
        {   'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory4',
            'id_macrocategory': 4,  
            'categories': []
        }
    ]
```

I have tried this, but the result is not correct and I don't know where is the problem. Or if there is a better way to obtain the desired result:

```
    output=[]
    macrocategory = '-'
    category = '-'
    d_macro = {}
    d_category = {}
    l_cat = []
    l_mic = []
    for dict_info in input:
        if macrocategory != int(dict_info['id_macrocategory']):
            macrocategory = int(dict_info['id_macrocategory'])
            category = '-' 
            if d_macro:
                d_category.update({'microcategories': l_mic})
                if d_category['id_category'] != 0:
                    l_cat.append(d_category)
                d_category = {}
                d_macro.update({'categories': l_cat})
                d_attributes['macro_categories'].append(d_macro)
                l_cat = []
                l_mic = []

            d_macro = {
                'id_macrocategory': int(dict_info['id_macrocategory']),
                'desc_macrocategory': dict_info['desc_macrocategory'],
                'categories': []
            }
        
        if category != int(dict_info['id_category']):
            category = int(dict_info['id_category'])
            if d_category:
                d_category.update({'microcategories': l_mic})
                if d_category['id_category'] != 0:
                    l_cat.append(d_category)
                    
                l_mic = []

            d_category = {
                'id_category': int(dict_info['id_category']),
                'desc_category': dict_info['desc_category'],
                'microcategories': []
            }

        d_micro = {
            'id_microcategory': int(dict_info['id_microcategory']),
            'desc_microcategory': dict_info['desc_microcategory'],
        }

        if d_micro['id_microcategory'] != 0:
            l_mic.append(d_micro)

    # for the last one
    d_category.update({'microcategories': l_mic})
    d_macro.update({'categories': l_cat})
    output.append(d_macro)
```

I cannot understand why I am loosing info in the output (the result is not showing me all the categories).

Comment: In case you're not already aware, all versions of Python 2 have been [deprecated as of January 1st, 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) and will no longer receive support or security updates. It is highly recommended that you migrate to Python 3 if at all possible.

Comment: macrocategory and microcategory give unboundlocalerror, referenced before assignment

Comment: yes thank you, but I need it in 2.7

Comment: yes, sorry. I already inserted the part of the code that was missing

Comment: can I just comment out the tools.dump2 and d_attributes (undefined)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to do everything at once, make a custom parser that makes objects for you that can represent what you really want, then iterate over your list of dictionaries, using the blocks to make what you want.

Collect up all the mappable names into a dict

```py
NAMES = {
    "desc": {
        "micro": "desc_macrocategory",
        "mid":   "desc_category",
        "macro": "desc_microcategory",
    },
    "id": {
        "micro": "id_macrocategory",
        "mid":   "id_category",
        "macro": "id_microcategory",
    },
    "category_listing": {
        "macro": "categories",
        "mid":   "microcategories",
        # no micro field
    }
}
```

create a custom object for your categories and to produce objects

```py
def Category():
    def __init__(self, name, category_level):
        self.category_name  = name
        self.category_level = category_level
        self.category_id    = None
        self.members = {}

    def export(self):
        # consider ensuring some needed members are non-None?
        d = {   # get field names from mapping
            NAMES["desc"][self.category_level]: self.category_name,
            NAMES["id"][self.category_level]:   self.category_id,
        }
        if self.category_level != "micro":  # maybe [], but not for micro
            d[NAMES["category_listing"][self.category_level]] = [c.export() for c in self.members.values()]
        return d
```

parse 'em out

```py
def category_parser(macro_categories, input_block):
    try:
        name_macro = input_block["desc_macrocategory"]
    except Exception:
        "whatever should happen if this fails"

    try:  # get the macro category or create a new one
        macro = macro_categories[name_macro]
    except KeyError:  # create a new Category for the macro name
        macro = Category(name_macro, "macro")
        macro_categories[category.name] = macro
        macro.category_id = input_block["id_macrocategory"]

    name_mid = input_block.get("desc_category")
    if name_mid:
        try:
            mid = macro.members["name_mid"]
        except KeyError:
            mid = Category(name_mid, "mid")
            macro.members[mid.name] = mid
            mid.id = input_block.get["id_category"]  # always set?

    name_micro = input_block.get("desc_microcategory")
    if name_micro:
        if not mid:
            raise ValueError("no middle member for micro member to reference")
        try:
            micro = mid.members["name_micro"]
        except KeyError:
            micro = Category(name_mid, "name_micro")
            mid.members[name_micro.name] = name_micro
            micro.id = input_block.get("id_microcategory")  # always set?
```

parse 'em all and then display

```
macro_categories = {}
for input_block in collection_of_dictionaries:  # don't clobber `input`
    category_parser(macro_categories, input_block)

{category.export() for category in macro_categories.values()}
```

It may be possible to use [`defaultDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of `try/except KeyError`, but I recall it's more awkward than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to unflatten the list (supposing the list is sorted by `id_macrocategory`):

```py
lst = [
    {
        "desc_category": "category1",
        "desc_macrocategory": "macrocategory1",
        "desc_microcategory": "microcategory1",
        "id_category": "1",
        "id_macrocategory": "1",
        "id_microcategory": "1",
    },
    {
        "desc_category": "category2",
        "desc_macrocategory": "macrocategory1",
        "desc_microcategory": None,
        "id_category": "2",
        "id_macrocategory": "1",
        "id_microcategory": "0",
    },
    {
        "desc_category": "category5",
        "desc_macrocategory": "macrocategory1",
        "desc_microcategory": None,
        "id_category": "5",
        "id_macrocategory": "1",
        "id_microcategory": "0",
    },
    {
        "desc_category": "category21",
        "desc_macrocategory": "macrocategory2",
        "desc_microcategory": None,
        "id_category": "21",
        "id_macrocategory": "2",
        "id_microcategory": "0",
    },
    {
        "desc_category": "category28",
        "desc_macrocategory": "macrocategory2",
        "desc_microcategory": None,
        "id_category": "28",
        "id_macrocategory": "2",
        "id_microcategory": "0",
    },
    {
        "desc_category": "category31",
        "desc_macrocategory": "macrocategory3",
        "desc_microcategory": "microcategory71",
        "id_category": "31",
        "id_macrocategory": "3",
        "id_microcategory": "71",
    },
    {
        "desc_category": "category31",
        "desc_macrocategory": "macrocategory3",
        "desc_microcategory": "microcategory72",
        "id_category": "31",
        "id_macrocategory": "3",
        "id_microcategory": "72",
    },
    {
        "desc_category": None,
        "desc_macrocategory": "macrocategory4",
        "desc_microcategory": None,
        "id_category": "0",
        "id_macrocategory": "4",
        "id_microcategory": "0",
    },
]


from pprint import pprint
from itertools import groupby


out = []
for v1, g1 in groupby(lst, lambda k: k["id_macrocategory"]):
    g1 = [*g1]
    out.append(
        {
            "desc_macrocategory": g1[0]["desc_macrocategory"],
            "id_macrocategory": v1,
            "categories": [],
        }
    )
    for v2, g2 in groupby(
        sorted(
            [g for g in g1 if int(g["id_category"]) != 0],
            key=lambda k: k["id_category"],
        ),
        lambda k: k["id_category"],
    ):
        g2 = [*g2]
        out[-1]["categories"].append(
            {
                "desc_category": g2[0]["desc_category"],
                "id_category": v2,
                "microcategories": [],
            }
        )
        for v3, g3 in groupby(
            sorted(
                [g for g in g2 if int(g["id_microcategory"]) != 0],
                key=lambda k: k["id_microcategory"],
            ),
            lambda k: k["id_microcategory"],
        ):
            g3 = [*g3]
            out[-1]["categories"][-1]["microcategories"].append(
                {
                    "desc_microcategory": g3[0]["desc_microcategory"],
                    "id_microcategory": v3,
                }
            )

pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[{'categories': [{'desc_category': 'category1',
                  'id_category': '1',
                  'microcategories': [{'desc_microcategory': 'microcategory1',
                                       'id_microcategory': '1'}]},
                 {'desc_category': 'category2',
                  'id_category': '2',
                  'microcategories': []},
                 {'desc_category': 'category5',
                  'id_category': '5',
                  'microcategories': []}],
  'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory1',
  'id_macrocategory': '1'},
 {'categories': [{'desc_category': 'category21',
                  'id_category': '21',
                  'microcategories': []},
                 {'desc_category': 'category28',
                  'id_category': '28',
                  'microcategories': []}],
  'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory2',
  'id_macrocategory': '2'},
 {'categories': [{'desc_category': 'category31',
                  'id_category': '31',
                  'microcategories': [{'desc_microcategory': 'microcategory71',
                                       'id_microcategory': '71'},
                                      {'desc_microcategory': 'microcategory72',
                                       'id_microcategory': '72'}]}],
  'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory3',
  'id_macrocategory': '3'},
 {'categories': [],
  'desc_macrocategory': 'macrocategory4',
  'id_macrocategory': '4'}]
```